# Insertion Sort in Python and Counting Comparisons/Swaps

Tags: python, python-3.x, insertion-sort

I currently have a correct implementation of an insertion sort function in Python and in the algorithm, I want to count the number of times a comparison is made and how many times elements are swapped. I believe I have the comparison part done correctly but I don't have the swap part done correctly. No matter how many times I test it, the number of swaps returned is always 0. Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

```
def insertion_sort(lyst):
    """
    This function implements the insertion sort algorithm to sort the items in lyst.
    The function returns a tuple containing the sorted list, followed by the number of
    comparisons, and finally the number of swaps performed while sorting. Lyst must be
    a Python list containing comparable data (i.e. things that the >,<, etc. operators
    can be used on to determine an ordering between two items). If lyst is not a list,
    insertion_sort() must raise a TypeError Exception.

    :param lyst: A list of integers to be sorted
    :return: A tuple containing the sorted list, followed by the number of
    comparisons, and finally the number of swaps performed while sorting
    """

    # Verify that lyst is a list and that every element in the list is an integer.
    if not isinstance(lyst, list) or not all(isinstance(x, int) for x in lyst):
        raise TypeError("lyst must be a list of comparable elements.")

    comparisons = 0  # Used to keep track of comparisons performed during the sort
    swaps = 0  # Used to keep track of swaps performed during the sort

    # Iterate over the elements of the list
    for i in range(1, len(lyst)):
        j = i

        # Insert number[i] into the sorted part, stopping once number[i] in the correct position
        while j > 0 and lyst[j] < lyst[j - 1]:
            # Swap numbers[j] and numbers[j - 1] using tuple
            lyst[j], lyst[j - 1] = lyst[j - 1], lyst[j]
            j -= 1
            # Increment swaps for each element swap
            swaps += 1

        # Increment comparisons for each element comparison
        comparisons += 1

    return lyst, comparisons, swaps
```

I've tried moving the swap to different lines and/or indentations but nothing is working.

Comment: I'm getting the swaps as expected can you post the example where you getting 0 for swaps

Comment: If I run your function, calling it with `insertion_sort([10,9,1,3,4,7,2,8,5,6])`, the result is `([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 9, 24)` - so the number of swaps returned is not `0` as you suggest. Please provide an example of use that has the unexpected result.

Comment: I figured out what I was doing wrong. It was my tests! Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code, and it is working fine.

If the list is already sorted or all the elements in the list are the same, only the swapped elements are shown as 0.

So you are good to go with this code itself.

If you still face the issue, the swap variable might be overwritten by other code in your project.

Otherwise, share your input. I will test you and tell you.